# Why does my kitchen faucet cut off when turned more than halfway on?

Tags: repair, faucet, kitchen-sink

A while back, I was running my kitchen faucet while the the dishwasher was on. While the dishwasher was filling up, there was a sudden spike in pressure in my pipes, and the faucet cut off. Ever since then, I can only turn my kitchen faucet about halfway on - it works normally up until that point, but then suddenly cuts off, and won't come back on until you completely turn off the faucet for several seconds.

I was able to disassemble the valve completely, but I can't figure out what the problem could be - everything looks ok (or at least not obviously broken) and nothing appears clogged.

How can I troubleshoot this? The faucet is a Kohler single lever faucet, if that helps.

Comment: Does this faucet have a separate sprayer attached, or is it a nozzle and spray in one? The diverter valve for a separate sprayer can get confused in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where the water comes out, see if there is a part to unscrew. Take it off and test again. This part can jam under higher flow/pressure.

Feel free to edit this to put in the correct name (aerator?)

Comment: Marking this as the answer, as I think it's the closest to what ended up fixing the issue. I had to replace the spray head: https://www.us.kohler.com/us//productDetail/sprayhead/1343556.htm?skuId=1343523

Comment: I think it _may_ have been possible to disassemble the spray head and replace a less costly part within, but I wasn't able to figure out the disassembly on my own, and the spray head replacement was only about $50 after tax.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to look for is a cartridge in the faucet. I had a large corner tub that we couldn't turn on the water full blast, meaning it took pert near an hour to fill up to usable levels. Changed out the cartridge that fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: @DanielGriscom, I was literally just doing that. Thanks for the head's up.

Comment: Coolness: and do keep 'em coming.